# Disable Radio Buttons If Hidden Div Displayed

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an `Asp.net` web application and on a page I have a `asp:textbox` which has a `OnTextChanged` function which checks my db and displays an error message (if required to).

The issue I have is that I want to disable the radio buttons.  I tried adding it in my code behind and also using `JQuery` but I cant get it to work as the message sometimes has a couple of seconds delay.

**HTML**

```
<asp:Label ID="removeUserNotExist" runat="server" Text="The user entered does not exist. Please try again." Visible="false" style="color: red"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="removeUserAlreadyListed" runat="server" Text="The user entered has already been submitted and is currently in the process of being removed from the list." Visible="false" style="color: red"></asp:Label>
<div class="form-group">        
     <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="txtRemoveUser" CssClass="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3 control-label">Enter Name To Be Removed</asp:Label>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
          <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtRemoveUser" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtRemoveUser_TextChanged" />
     </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
     <asp:Label runat="server" CssClass="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3 control-label">
          <b>Request For</b>
     </asp:Label>
     <div class="col-sm-3">
          <label class="radio-inline">
               <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbRemoveYourself" GroupName="RemoveRequestFor" /> Yourself
          </label>
          <label class="radio-inline">
               <asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbRemoveOtherUser" GroupName="RemoveRequestFor" /> Other User
          </label>
     </div>
</div>
```

**Current JQuery (This is used to keep my button disabled)**

```
$("#MainContent_txtRemoveUser").on("blur", function ()
        {
            disableButton();
        });

function disableButton()
        {
            var isRbRemoveSelfChecked = $("#MainContent_rbRemoveYourself").is(':checked')
            var isRbRemoveOtherChecked = $("#MainContent_rbRemoveOtherUser").is(':checked')

            if ($('#MainContent_txtRemoveUser').val() != '' && $("#MainContent_removeUserNotExist").is(':visible') || $("#MainContent_removeUserAlreadyListed").is(':visible'))
            {
                $("#MainContent_btnRemoveUser").prop('disabled', true);
            }
            else if ($('#MainContent_txtRemoveUser').val() != '' && isRbRemoveSelfChecked)
            {
                $("#MainContent_btnRemoveUser").prop('disabled', false);
            }
            else if ($('#MainContent_txtRemoveSubmitterName').val() == '' && isRbRemoveOtherChecked)
            {
                $("#MainContent_btnRemoveUser").prop('disabled', true);

                $("#MainContent_txtRemoveSubmitterName").on("blur", function ()
                {
                    if ($('#MainContent_txtRemoveSubmitterName').val() != '')
                    {
                        $("#MainContent_btnRemoveUser").prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#MainContent_btnRemoveUser").prop('disabled', true);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $("#MainContent_btnRemoveUser").prop('disabled', true);
            }
        }
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void txtRemoveUser_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PaydayLunchConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);

    #region Checks the 'Users' db
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT 1 FROM Users WHERE Name = @Name", conn);
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtRemoveUser.Text);
    SqlDataReader rd1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

    if (rd1.HasRows)
    {
        removeUserNotExist.Visible = false;
        rbRemoveYourself.Enabled = false; (This is what I tried adding)
    }
    else
    {
        removeUserNotExist.Visible = true;
        rbRemoveYourself.Enabled = true; (This is what I tried adding)
    }
    conn.Close();
    #endregion
}
```

I also tried the following `JQuery`

```
$("#MainContent_txtRemoveUser").on("blur", function ()
{
    disableButton();

    if ($('#MainContent_removeUserNotExist').text() == '')
    {
        $('#MainContent_rbRemoveYourself').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

What I'm after is, if `<asp:Label ID="removeUserNotExist">` OR `<asp:Label ID="removeUserAlreadyListed"` are displayed I want my radio buttons to be disabled.

Comment: after text change you want to disable radiobutton ?

Comment: First remove label text value... Set Value Only if it returns true/false and then check if($("#labelid").text != ' ' )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change This

```
<asp:Label ID="removeUserNotExist" runat="server" Text="The user entered does not exist. Please try again." Visible="false" style="color: red"></asp:Label>
<asp:Label ID="removeUserAlreadyListed" runat="server" Text="The user entered has already been submitted and is currently in the process of being removed from the list." Visible="false" style="color: red"></asp:Label>
```

With This

```
 <asp:Label ID="removeUserNotExist" runat="server"  Visible="false" style="color: red"></asp:Label>
 <asp:Label ID="removeUserAlreadyListed" runat="server" Visible="false" style="color: red"></asp:Label>


OnTextChanged Event : Set your Label Value
```

then call Javascript Function On ServerSide,

```
 function disableradioButton() {
    if ($('#MainContent_removeUserNotExist').text() != '')
    {
        $('#MainContent_rbRemoveYourself').prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }



ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "Javascript:disableradioButton();", true);
```